# Query String from the URL

Tags: c#, url, query-string

I have an application URL that can be launched from browser with query string passed in.

My Development URL is

```
http://localhost:15094/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin
```

Client URL will be path to MyPage.html in the hard Drive

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Client/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin
```

When the url is localhost with http, i can extract the query string using

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query
// this gives me ?user=username&role=admin 
// from http://localhost:15094/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin
```

But I want ?user=username&role=admin when client use the URL

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Client/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin
```

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query does not work with it I suppose.

Please note Development URL is with http and when the application is installed on a Client's machine, the url will be without http, this is how application should work. Please do not suggest to host it in IIS etc.

My Question is very simple:

How would you extract the query string from "**file:///C:/Program%20Files/Client/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin**" ?
If System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query works fine for url's without http, why I am not getting query string right?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you looked at the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri) class?

Comment: if i use System.Uri, it replaces MyPage.htmn?user=username to MyPage.html%3Fuser=username :( so no luck with that. basically "?" will be converted to "%3F" when URL without http

Comment: @John `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query` _is_ a `System.Uri`. @Vinnie the percent-encoding is most likely done because a path on Windows may not contain question marks. See also [file URI scheme on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). I think the real question here is whether you actually want such URIs, but I'm sure if you must you can grab the query part using some `IndexOf()` and `Substring()` on the original URI string.

Comment: @CodeCaster - thats is one of the possibility I can make use of. but when you have a very large query string with loads of parameters passed in, HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query) will be reaaly helpful to get the parameter value by specifying the key. 
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
var newQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
sQSValue = newQueryString[key].ToString();

Comment: You can just pass the string you obtained with `Substring()` to `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

Comment: Interesting. What's your scenario for using a file: URL with a query string? I'm a little surprised that it doesn't work, but I'm even more surprised that you _want_ it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this without being clever is to use IndexOf eg:

```
var originalUrl = "file:///C:/Program%20Files/Client/MyPage.html?user=username&role=admin";
var extractedQueryString = string.Empty;
if(originalUrl.IndexOf("?") != -1)
{
   extractedQueryString = originalUrl.Substring(originalUrl.IndexOf("?"));
}
```

Wrote this off the top of my head without compiling but think I got it right.

Also to get the filename part of the string if you're wondering would be:

```
var extractedFileName = originalUrl.Substring(0, originalUrl.IndexOf("?"));
```

Comment: How would you populate the originalURL though?